# How to use join to fill missing values of a column - Python Pandas?

Tags: python, join, pandas, left-join, concatenation

To be concrete, say we have two DataFrames:

df1:

```
date    A
12/1/14 3
12/2/14 NaN
12/3/14 2
12/2/14 NaN
12/4/14 NaN
12/6/14 5
```

df2:

```
        B
12/2/14 20
12/4/14 30
```

I want to do kind of a left outer join to fill the missing values in df1, and generate

df3:

```
date    A
12/1/14 3
12/2/14 20
12/3/14 2
12/2/14 20
12/4/14 30
12/6/14 5
```

Any efficient way to make it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combine_first` (only the columns names should match, therefore I first rename the column B in df2):

```
In [8]: df2 = df2.rename(columns={'B':'A'})

In [9]: df1.combine_first(df2)
Out[9]:
          A
12/1/14   3
12/2/14  20
12/2/14  20
12/3/14   2
12/4/14  30
12/6/14   5
```